# Attendance at a dinner party

Tags: lateral-thinking, family

In the late 1400's, a Count, who is hosting a dinner party, receives a message from his steward. 
The note lists that the following relatives of the Count will be attending the party:

> - The father's brother-in-law
> - The brother's father-in-law
> - The father-in-law's brother
> - The brother-in-law's father

The Count immediately assumes that there will be four guests. However, the steward's message makes him seem less sure.

***What is the least number of guests that the Count can expect?***

Comment: For this problem, are you allowing either remarrying or incest? Those could be used to reduce the number.

Comment: I want to add an answer as "No Party" and explanation as "Consequences" :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's:

> They could all be the same person in a totally respectable manner.

Because:

> The father's brother-in-law isn't necessary his uncle.  The father could have remarried.
>  The brother's father-in-law could be that person if the father's new wife is his brother's wife's mother.
>  The father-in-law's brother is also the same person if he's his wife's father's brother.
>  The brother-in-law's father can still be the same person if his wife's her brother's mother remarried her ex's brother.

Comment: This answer is correct, as it does not involve marrying more than one person, as does the other answer. Good job!

Comment: This could be simplified if you remember that brother-in-law can also mean your sister's husband (or brother's husband if you like) not just your spouse's brother.

Answer (score 8):

> Zero other than himself.

The count is married to his aunt, thus his father's brother-in-law is himself.
The count is also married to his mum (he's a mormon or something, allowing multiple marriages). Thus his brother's father in law is himself. 
The count's mum is also married to his brother, thus the father-in-law's brother is himself.
The count's sister is married to the count's son, thus the brother in law's father is himself.

O_o

Comment: What a rude Count!

Comment: Please always put your answer in the spoilers.

Comment: @question_asker Rude and lonely

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading this wrong (it gets very confusing!) but being married to his brother's mother would only make him the brother's stepfather, not father-in-law. It does work if you say that his brother is married to their sister (spouse's [step]father).

Answer (score 5):

If we do not consider any incest or multiple marriages then answer is:

> Three

Because his brother's father-in-law and his father-in-law's brother can be the same guy given that his brother marries a cousin of his wife.

Answer (score 0):

Since text explanations can get really confusing really fast, I made a diagram to better visualize the relationships with the person(s) in question.

> [image: Dinner Party Visualization]

Key:

- `Count` = Red circle
- `The father's brother-in-law` = Green
- `The brother's father-in-law` = Pink
- `The father-in-law's brother` = Blue
- `The brother-in-law's father` = Orange